# AllowAny for get method in djangorestframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use django rest framework,
example code

```
class TestApiView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        return Response({'text': 'allow any'})

    def post(self, request):
        return Response({'text': 'IsAuthenticated'})
```

how to make method GET accessible to all, and method POST only authorized

thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticatedorreadonly) permission class:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly

class TestApiView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def get(self, request):
        return Response({'text': 'allow any'})

    def post(self, request):
        return Response({'text': 'IsAuthenticated'})
```

Comment: Thank you very much